# Как сделать `bb` коды для форума?

Tags: php, форум, bbcode

Как сделать `bb` коды, ну то есть чтобы выделить или подчеркнуть.

Comment: а поиском пользуемся? http://hashcode.ru/questions/147573/html-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-bb-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83

Comment: Извините, но не могу интернет очень медленный (фигов МТС с его трафиком)

Comment: Там ссылка на ирбис была попробовал всё равно не выходит

Answer (score 1):

Перед добавлением в базу удаляешь все HTML теги и пропускаешь через PHP функцию

```
//BB coder
    function bb_code($mes) {
        $mes=htmlspecialchars($mes);
        $mes=stripslashes($mes);
        $mes=trim($mes);
        $mes=str_replace("\n"," <br/>",$mes);
        $mes=str_replace("[b]"," <b>",$mes); $mes=str_replace("[/b]"," </b>",$mes);
        $mes=str_replace("[i]"," <i>",$mes); $mes=str_replace("[/i]"," </i>",$mes);
        $mes=str_replace("[u]"," <u>",$mes); $mes=str_replace("[/u]"," </u>",$mes);
        return $mes;
    }
```

Можно дополнить еще кучей. то есть ты придуманный тобой тег [b] заменяешь на < b>
.